# How to dynamicall assign errors to lightning:datatable errors attribute

Tags: lightning, datatable

I created a CSV parser that takes any combination of Salesforce Object.Field and displays the parsed results in a lightning:datatable. Documentation for [lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) provides the following example for assigning errors to the errors attribute:

```
triggerError(event) {
       this.errors = {
            rows: {
                b: {
                    title: 'We found 2 errors.',
                    messages: [
                        'Enter a valid amount.',
                        'Verify the email address and try again.'
                    ],
                    fieldNames: ['amount', 'contact']
                }
            },
            table: {
                title: 'Your entry cannot be saved. Fix the errors and try again.',
                messages: [
                    'Row 2 amount must be number',
                    'Row 2 email is invalid'
                ]
            }
        };
    }
```

However I need to generate these values dynamically. So I created a string matching the above and then do:

```
this.errors = JSON.parse(errorsAsString);
```

This throws a parsing error on 'r' (in 'rows') because the value in the example is not valid JSON in the sense that rows, title, messages, etc. are not quoted. Rather, they are references to objects Lightning creates at runtime.

Then I try:

```
this.errors = eval(errorsAsString);
```

...and that works perfectly, except that eval is an obvious no-no.

My hunch is that I need to create a JavaScript object with the same structure, but I'm not sure how to create one with this structural complexity. Nor do I know how to convert a string representation of the row's key-field, 'b', into an object reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're supposed to make an actual object.

```
let errors = {};
errors.rows = {};
errors.rows[rowId] = { title: 'We found an error', messages: [ 'Enter a valid amount.' ], fields: [ 'amount' };
// ... etc
this.errors = errors;
```

If you insist on using JSON, you could, but you'll need to quote everything:

```
this.errors = JSON.parse('{ "rows": { "b": { "title": "We found an error" }, "messages": [ "Enter a valid amount." ], "fields": [ "amount" ]}, ...}');
```

The example source is meant to demonstrate how it's designed to be laid out, but in real code, you'd be creating objects, arrays, etc, as demonstrated above.